# Adjusting table view cell height to fit buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

Im trying to get my table view cells to look like the one on the main storyboard.  I have a label then below it, two buttons.  I cant get the cell to display everything only one line of the label.  Ive been able to increase the height with the label but not to fit everything.  I want it to look like the storyboard cell but instead it looks like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, what are you doing about it? You are in charge of cell height.

Comment: @Michael.R just increase cell height, and don't post images of code.

Comment: Down-voted because this feels like you just don't understand. Look into `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`.

Comment: @dfd or set up the cells properly with autolayout and use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. But yeah, either way it's pretty obvious that the cells are too short.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using these functions I Don't think so , Just use these default Delegates provided with UITableView And see if it helps you

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Secondly, if you are using tableView from Storyboard

untick Row height from custom

[image]